# react previous state not being updated

Tags: reactjs

**Home.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Home = ({setSelectedGame}) => {

    const [search, setSearch] = useState({
        type: false,
        category: '',
        searchBar: ''
    })

    const filterSearch = e => {
        setSearch({category: e.target.id})
        console.log(search.category)
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            
            <ul className='categories'>
                <li><a onClick={(e) => filterSearch(e)} id='All'>All</a></li>
                <li><a onClick={(e) => filterSearch(e)} id='Action'>Action</a></li>
                <li><a onClick={(e) => filterSearch(e)} id='Adventure'>Adventure</a></li>
                <li><a onClick={(e) => filterSearch(e)} id='Survival'>Survival</a></li>
                <li><a onClick={(e) => filterSearch(e)} id='Simulation'>Simulation</a></li>
                <li><a onClick={(e) => filterSearch(e)} id='Racing'>Racing</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Whenever I click on Action search.category = Action, then  when I click on All search.category is still the same, only when I click on All twice does the state get updated... I know this is simple but I'm not able to find a solution, i can use ... on arrays but doesnt seem like I can use it here.(on objects)

Comment: Are you checking value by console.log()? It is wrong because setState is async. Also, with your state update you are removing all the keys from object only keeping category. Is that what you wnt?

Comment: no,i want to update the category when the user clicks on a specific one

Comment: you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals):

```
const filterSearch = e => setSearch({...search, ...{category: e.target.id}});
```